# $\mathrm{Tor}$ functor not left exact

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, derived-functors

Is there an example which shows that the functor $B\otimes_R(-)$ is not left-exact, given a ring $R$ and a right $R$-module $B$?

Answer (score 10):

Consider the one-to-one function of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules
$$\begin{align*}
f\colon\mathbb{Z}&\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\\
a&\longmapsto 2a
\end{align*}$$

If we tensor with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the map $f$ induces a map
$$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$
that sends 
$\overline{1}\otimes 1$ to $$\overline{1}\otimes f(1) = \overline{1}\otimes 2 = \overline{1}\otimes (1+1) = \overline{1}\otimes 1 + \overline{1}\otimes 1= \mathbf{0}.$$
So the map induced by the one-to-one map $f$ is not one-to-one.